# MassTransing SQS/SNS - how to enable encryption at rest on all topics

Tags: masstransit

I know that to enable encryption at rest for SNS Topics I need to add topic attribute like this one

```
cfg.Publish<SomeEvent>(p =>
{
    p.TopicAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.KmsMasterKeyId, "<key arn>");
});
```

But the problem I have is that we are using very simple configuration for aspnetcore with UsingAmazonSQS and cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context) doing all those configurations automatically so there is no call to cfg.Publish. This is very important as we have many messages to configure. I believe the same thing for queue attributes can be achieved by registering custom implementation of IConfigureReceiveEndpoint but I can't find equivalent for topics.

How can I keep using the automatic method and add this encryption topic attribute for all topics?

Comment: Added, it should be in the latest prerelease package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to apply topic attributes to all topics, but it isn't an unreasonable request for an addition. Surely someone can build it as a pull request adding to the general publish topology for Amazon SQS.

### Update

I [added the ability](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2700) to specify attributes on the root `PublishTopology` which should be applied to all topics.

Used in code (from the comment below):

```cs
configure.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) => 
{
   cfg.PublishTopology.TopicAttributes
       .Add(QueueAttributeName.KmsMasterKeyId, encryptionKeyArn); 

   cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});
```

Comment: As a thank you here are few more details if any will be trying to use this new functionality (available since v7.2.2) - making all topics encrypted is now as simple as 

`configure.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) => {  
 cfg.PublishTopology.TopicAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.KmsMasterKeyId, encryptionKeyArn); cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context); })`